# How to get External js host origin by jQuery/Js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get host domain of an external script. For example:

```
<script src="//api.host.com/some.js">
```

Inside `some.js`:

```
console.log("Hi root domain, I am coming from " + document.referrer);
```

I want the `some.js` script to detect where it is hosted. Is this possible? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a built-in method of achieving this, but you can use:

```
var fileName = "some.js"
var hostedAt;
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");
for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
    let split = scripts[i].src.split(/\//g);
    if (split[split.length-1] === fileName) {
        split[split.length-1] = "";
        split = split.join("/");
        hostedAt = split;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's why I love programming than my GF. Thank you so much.